# Best use of unordered_map for 3D hasing: should I use unions as keys and how?

Tags: c++, c++11, unions, unordered-map

I would like to use C++11 [std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) for hashing points on regular rectangular grid in 3D (2D,4D).

Originally I was doing manual packing and unpacking of index like this:

```
inline int_fast64_t xyz2i( int_fast16_t ix, int_fast16_t iy, int_fast16_t iz ){
     return ix | ( iy << 16 ) | ( iz << 32 );
}

inline void i2xyz( int_fast64_t i, int_fast16_t& ix, int_fast16_t& iy, int_fast16_t& iz ){
    iz=( i & 0xFF0000 ) >> 32;
    iy=( i & 0x00FF00 ) >> 16;
    ix=( i & 0x0000FF );
}
```

then I realized that using [unions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) would be probably better:

```
class NodeIndex4D{
    public:
    union{
        struct{ int_fast16_t x,y,z,w; };
        int_fast16_t array[4];
        int_fast64_t i;
    };
};
```

but still, I have feeling that I don't do it the best way. That C++ language features can be used perhaps better for this purpose.

E.g. what is not so nice is my `insertNode` function:

```
std::unordered_map<int_fast64_t,Node> nodes;

Node& insertNode( int_fast16_t ix, int_fast16_t iy, int_fast16_t iz ){
    NodeIndex4D inod; 
    inod.x=ix; inod.y=iy; inod.z=iz; inod.w=0;  // NOT SO NICE
    int sz0 = nodes.size();
    Node& node = nodes[inod.i]; // get valid reference ( if new allocate, if old take it )
    if( nodes.size() > sz0 ){ // new element
        node.id = sz0;
        index2pos( {ix,iy,iz}, node.pos ); // not relevant here 
        node.pos.add_mul( scaling, -0.5 ); // not relevant here
    }
    return node;
}
```

It is probably not possible to do something like `std::unordered_map<NodeIndex4D,Node>` which would use standard hash function on `NodeIndex4D.i` ?

also I was considering to define my insert function as
`Node& insertNode( NodeIndex4D inod )` and call it as `Node& insertNode( {ix,iy,iz,0} )`

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: What's your question? And can you give some feedback on my answer to your last question? You seem to have abandoned it.

Comment: *"// NOT SO NICE"* - you can write constructors for `NodeIndex4D`, overloaded or with default values for some arguments, allowing you to write `NodeIndex4D inod { ix, iy, iz };` directly.  Still, the big problem with your `union` is aliasing - C++ has undefined behaviour if you set values using the `int16_t` fields then read them using `int_fast64_t i;` or vice versa.  Your implementation might or might not stipulate its own behaviour that might or might not make your code work reliably - you'd have to check your compiler docs, if you don't care about portability.

Comment: Separately, your unpacking - `iz=( i & 0xFF0000 ) >> 32;` / `iy=( i & 0x00FF00 ) >> 16;` if off - you'll always get `0`.  Check your bit positions.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - yes, sorry, I replied

Comment: Tony D - Aha, thanks, I did not know that about undefined behaviour. So you recommend to keep up with manual packing / unpacking ?

Answer (score 1):

A *partially portable* way would be to alias an `int64_t` to an array of 4 `int16_t`. Even if it is not explicitely allowed by the standard, it should work on any common architecture that supports both `int16_t` and `int64_t` (all I know do).

The only tricky part would be endianness that should be tested at the beginning of the program in a static element to say whether x,y,z,w ranks are 0,1,2,3 or 3,2,1,0 repectively. Following code should do the trick:

```
class Node4D {
    uint64_t packed;
    uint16_t (& unpacked)[4];

    static bool isBigEndian() {
        static bool inited = false;
        static bool bigEndian = false;
        if (! inited) {
            Node4D n;
            inited = true;
            n.packed = 1;
            bigEndian = (n.unpacked[0] == 0);
        }
        return bigEndian;
    }

public:
    Node4D(): unpacked(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t (&)[4]>(packed)) {
        packed = 0;
    }
    Node4D(uint64_t p): unpacked(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t (&)[4]>(packed)) {
        packed = p;
    }
    Node4D(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t z, uint16_t w):
    unpacked(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t (&)[4]>(packed)) {
        set(x, y, z, w);
    }
    uint64_t get() {
        return packed;
    }
    void get(uint16_t& x,uint16_t& y,uint16_t& z,uint16_t& w) {
        if (isBigEndian()) {
            w = unpacked[0];
            z = unpacked[1];
            y = unpacked[2];
            x = unpacked[3];
        }
        else {
            x = unpacked[0];
            y = unpacked[1];
            z = unpacked[2];
            w = unpacked[3];
        }
    }

    void set(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t z, uint16_t w) {
        if (isBigEndian()) {
            unpacked[0] = w;
            unpacked[1] = z;
            unpacked[2] = y;
            unpacked[3] = x;
        }
        else {
            unpacked[0] = x;
            unpacked[1] = y;
            unpacked[2] = z;
            unpacked[3] = w;
        }
    }
};
```

Internally, the struct only contains one single 8 bytes long element, so it can safely be used as a key.

Comment: thanks, I should read it carefully once more. Also I should figure out what exactly `uint16_t (& unpacked)[4];` means

Comment: @ProkopHapala: It is used to alias a reference to an `int64_t` to a reference to an array of 4 `int16_t`.

Comment: that I understand, but I don't get what it means in general ( i.e. how it fits to general logic of C++ syntax ) .... how it differs from `uint16_t& unpacked[4];` etc.